# Set the filter items operator to "OR" instead of "AND"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on the XGrid where I need to filter the rows based on the checkboxes selected on my page. I am trying to pass the items into the filterItems prop for creation of many filters, but seem to have no idea as to how to set the operator from being AND by default to OR.

I know that the filterItems takes in GridFilterModel but there is 0 docs regarding the structure of that object. I would appreciate someones help in finding that out.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer. In order to change the filtering to Or, you need to

```
import { GridLinkOperator } from "@material-ui/x-grid";
```

in the filterModel object besides items include the following:

```
{
 items:[],
 linkOperator: GridLinkOperator.Or,
}
```